# Is there a library to convert triton server model config to json

Tags: tensorrt, tritonserver

I am looking for below config.pbtxt file to be converted to json. Are there any libraries or is there any easy way to do it?

```
platform: "tensorrt_plan"
  max_batch_size: 8
  input [
    {
      name: "input0"
      data_type: TYPE_FP32
      dims: [ 16 ]
    },
    {
      name: "input1"
      data_type: TYPE_FP32
      dims: [ 16 ]
    }
  ]
  output [
    {
      name: "output0"
      data_type: TYPE_FP32
      dims: [ 16 ]
    }
  ]
```